# Starting multiple multiprocessing Managers becomes extremely slow

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In my python application I need to start more than one multiprocessing.Manager. I seems that upon the start of a second manager, all objects referenced in the first one gets an INCREF. 
On the third start, all objects created by the first and the second manager get another INCREF. And so on.
I cannot understand why the start of a totally new manager, in a new process, will cause all these INCREF about object hosted on other managers - which cause the program to take forever to start/stop.

This small script fully reproduces the behaviour, tested in python 2.7 and 3.2:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import multiprocessing, logging
# # Activate multiprocessing logging
mplog = multiprocessing.get_logger()
mplog.setLevel(multiprocessing.util.DEBUG)
mplog.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
objs=[]
def newman(n=50):
    global objs
    m=multiprocessing.Manager()
    print('created')
    for i in range(n):
        objs.append(m.Value('i',i)) 
    return m    

print('#### first man')
m1=newman()

print ('#### second man')
m2=newman()

print ('#### third man')
m3=newman(0)
```

After the start of the first manager, the logger prints out the messages relative to the creation of the first 50 objects.

But when the second manager is starting - before any object was created by it - the logger prints out exactly 50 INCREF messages.Then follows the messages relating to the creation of the 50 new objects on manager 2.

When the third manager starts - before any object was created by it - 100 more INCREF messages are printed.

No object creation message is seen after m3 creation, as I passed 0 to the newman() function.

When the program ends, a similar amount of DECREF messages is printed.

It seems that, when I start a new manager, it creates a reference to all objects referenced by previous managers. In a big application this translates into **extremely slow** startup/shutdown.

Any workaround? Or at least, any explanation about why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

```
class BaseProxy(object):
     # ...
     def _incref(self):
         # ...
         util.debug('INCREF %r', self._token.id)
     # ...
     def _after_fork(self):
         # ...
         self._incref()
         # ...
```

You are using a linux machine that uses fork to create new processes.
Idea: Each time you start a manager the currrent process is forked and _incref is called.

1. Help me to prove it: first create all managers, then create new values. Is this still increasing references?
2. have a look at the implementation.

Comment: Yes, I think you got it... Still wandering **why** is it like that, and If there is a way to avoid it. Why should each proxied object increase its own count each time the main process is forked? They do not get more references after the fork...

Comment: A fork copies the whole process memory. So after the fork there is one more copy of the proxy object in the new process. Since this proxy object could be used the reference counter needs to be increased.

Comment: How could a new manager process use any object referenced in the first manager object...? And also, why don't we have this problem if we start all the managers first, then create objects later? It seems that forking isn't a good option for manager startup: manager processes should be lightweight and have no need to copy the whole main process memory... Is there a way to avoid that? Should I try calling server_forever in a new Process object?